# Are “Rings” in fish like rings in a tree?

Tags: physiology

A lot of fish have structures like the rings in a tree. Is the number of “rings” an indicator of age, as in a tree, or is it fixed?

Comment: Can you please clarify about what structure you are talking about. You could for example upload a picture with a clear red arrow pointing to the structure of interest. In any case, the answer will probably be "no, it does not indicate age".

Comment: I am VTC as unclear as the OP has not clarified what structure she is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

It depends which structures you're talking about. However, several body parts of bony fish such as the scales and otoliths (earbones) generally contain a record of seasonal growth patterns. So in that sense yes, the process of ageing fish is similar to finding the age of a tree by counting rings in the wood. For different species of fish, different structures are used to determine ages.

https://www.nefsc.noaa.gov/fbp/basics.htm